# How can i add image at the end of existing pdf file using iText

Tags: java, image, position, itext, pdfstamper

I have an existing pdf file that i'm reading with pdfreader and using pdfstamper to add some images and text into the temporary pdf file. The problem I'm facing is that Images are getting added to contentbyte but some of them are not visible and some of those are getting overlapped with each other as my scenario is to add screenshot to this pdf file after some point(at every failed step while running my selenium webdriver).I've tried setting different positions but nothing worked perfectly. I need to resolve this issue on priority.Please suggest what should i do to add image at bottom of existing pdf every time it needs to be added.

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(sScreenShotFileName);
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader,new 
FileOutputStream(tempfile));
PdfContentByte content = pdfStamper.getUnderContent(i);
Font f = new Font();
f.setStyle(Font.BOLD);
f.setSize(8);
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText( content );
ct.setText(new Phrase(new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-YYYY HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()),f));
ct.go();          
File src= ((TakesScreenshot)oDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(src, new 
File(sSVNfolderPath+"\\Log_Files\\Snapshots\\Test.jpg"));
FileInputStream pic = new 
FileInputStream(sSVNfolderPath+"\\Log_Files\\Snapshots\\Test.jpg");
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(pic);
java.awt.Image image = ImageIO.read(is);
Image img = Image.getInstance(image,null);
img.scalePercent(x);
img.setAbsolutePosition(x, y);
content.addImage(img);
pdfStamper.close();
pdfReader.close();
new File(sScreenShotFileName).delete();
new File(tempfile).renameTo(new File(sScreenShotFileName));
y=y*2;//setting y position to upward every time where the new image can be placed.
```

Thanks,
Meenal

Comment: Using the same value as **x** coordinate and as zoom  factor is weird. Doubling the **y** coordinate after each image does not appear sensible either. And you are using the UnderContent, so it is quite plausible some parts of your images are covered.

Comment: Hi mkl,I'm now able to add multiple images using insert page but the problem is now 'inserted page's size'.Page size is very bigger than i need. How can I reduce the page height while adding?

Comment: By setting the **CropBox** of the page accordingly.